# What does here "yielded" mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Each mandrel yielded in two 125 × 125 mm2 plates which were ground and cut into samples of 120 × 7 x 2.5 mm³ for tensile tests.
Is here "yielded" used in the meaning of "produce"? As the result, each mandrel produced (gave) two 125 × 125 mm2 plates....

Comment: I'm not sure what the context is here, but _yielded_ can certainly mean _produced_ (we can speak of a field or tree yielding a crop). NB The past tense of _grind_ is _ground_.

Comment: "Yielded" is transitive: it takes a direct object. "Yielded in" is incorrect. The phrase "125 x 125 mm2" makes no sense. If the plate is 125 mm x 125 mm, it has an area of 15,625 mm^2. The same applies to the description "120 x 7 x 2.5 mm3". If you are giving edge dimensions, don't use "mm2" or "mm3".